# Natural gas water heater air intake requirement

Tags: water-heater, natural-gas

I'm replacing a natural gas water heater in my house with a new natural gas water heater. The current one is a 40 gallon 40,000 BTU water heater and I'm looking to replace it with a 75 gallon 76,000 BTU water heater. My current natural gas set up has the capacity for the increased BTUs, but I'm unsure of the air intake situation.

My current water heater has a dedicated air intake pipe run from the outside to the water heater. The water heater I'm looking to get says it just pulls ambient air from around the tank and doesn't require a dedicated intake run. The space where the water heater is going is a 12x12 utility room so there is plenty of space. They're both power vented water heaters as well.

Do I need to use the fresh air intake with the new water heater or can I just remove that run and cap it?

Comment: Most fuel using heaters these days use outside air, since most newer houses are sealed well.  Back in the 60s/70s houses leaked well enough not to need outside air.  All air that is used for burning fuel has to be replaced, either by sucking cold air into the whole house or by a small pipe to the outside.  It is odd for a new heater not to use/need an outside pipe.

Comment: How old is your house? Has it been air sealed? For efficiency's sake you'll probably want the old intake with a gravity damper regardless, just for efficiency's sake.

Comment: The house was built in 2017. The new heater has the option to use a separate air intake according to the manual, but makes it sound like it is optional. I'll plan to use the existing air intake. I should also add the utility room is in the unfinished basement

Comment: https://www.heattreattoday.com/media-category/commentary/op-ed/excess-air-its-role-in-combustion-and-heat-transfer/

Comment: a fresh air intake (directly to the burner) should not be used whenever possible.  Taking cold outside winter air and feeding that directly into the combustion chamber reduces efficiency; you will use more fuel.

Comment: rule of thumb is 10 cfm per 1 cfm of natural gas burning; natural gas has 1037 BTU's per cubic foot, from there you can do the math to obtain air cfm requirements.

Comment: @ron That's not true. In the winter if you take inside air all the happened is your furnace heated it. It's always better to take outside air.

Comment: @Ariel - *it's always better to take outside air* ... ask that at ACHRnews, PMmagazine, any credible industry technical place, see what they say.  Your missing the big picture in terms of efficiency and where heat is going or being lost.  Always taking in outside air cools the combustion chamber X° when you could've taken advantage of already warmed air.  It is not always better to take outside air.